# How can we measure the bandwidth for Ms Dynamics CRM?

Tags: bandwidth, crm

We have to measure the bandwidth that Ms Dynamics CRM use. Does anybody know if there is an application for this issue or another way through our server? 
(Windows Server 2003 R2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a nice article on http://blogs.iis.net

**[Measuring incoming and outgoing bandwidth per Application Pool](http://blogs.iis.net/thomad/archive/2010/03/31/measuring-incoming-and-outgoing-bandwidth-per-application-pool.aspx)**

> IIS has a per Web-Site performance counter that measures bandwidth ("Web Service", "Bytes Received/sec" and Web Service", "Bytes Sent/sec"). The problem is that this only measures the bandwidth for requests that make it to user mode. All requests that get cached by HTTP.SYS in kernel-mode will not be measured.
>   The good thing is that HTTP.SYS has the same performance counters ("HTTP Service Url Groups", "BytesReceivedRate" and "HTTP Service UrlGroups", "BytesSentRate").

The blog post also contains a **PowerShell script** that creates a nice output of bandwidth usage of each application pool.